# JS toggle visibility and change css of other items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm sure this is incredibly simple but I'm pretty new to JS and I'd like to know the best way of doing this rather than hacking it out with a workaround.

So I have a div block and it's visibility is toggled when pressing a text field above it.

```
<h3 onclick="javascript: toggle1();">
  <span style="cursor:pointer">
    <b>Text1</b>
  </span>
</h3>

<div id="Text1" hidden="hidden">blahblah</div>
```

And then I have my JS:

```
function toggle1() {
  $('#Text1').toggle(1000);
}
```

This works fine, however when the user clicks the header text I also want to alter the height of a `<hr>` element above it

```
<hr id="line1" style="height:2px;border:none;color:#03930f;background-color:#03930f;" />
```

I have tried adding:

```
if($('#Text1').is(':visible')) {
  document.getElementById("line1").style.height = "15px";
}
else { 
  document.getElementById("line1").style.height = "2px"; 
}
```

but this doesn't work...I assume because the toggle() function doesn't toggle the same thing the `is(':visible')` condition is checking.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Can we have your code in fiddle.

Comment: Is that what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/xLxsctfk/1/

Comment: @guvenckardas - updated to *work* http://jsfiddle.net/xLxsctfk/2/

Comment: @Jamiec thanks for editing

Comment: Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Answer - first pass

`.toggle` *does* affect the `:visible` status of an element, but having given it a duration (`1000`) its not immediate, which means if you want something to happen *after it's finished* it needs to be supplied in an optional callback:

```
$('#Text1').toggle(1000,function(){
    if($('#Text1').is(':visible')) {
        document.getElementById("line1").style.height = "15px";
    }
    else { document.getElementById("line1").style.height = "2px"; }
});
```

### Answer - second pass

You're mixing jquery and vanilla javascript - while there is nothing wrong with that inherantly, it's a bit confusing. Stick to one or the other. Helpfully, inside a callback you can refer to the element using `$(this)`, and as you already know elements can be targetted by id using `#elementId`

```
$('#Text1').toggle(1000,function(){
    if($(this).is(':visible')) {
         $('#line1').css('height','15px');
    }
    else { 
         $('#line1').css('height','2px');
    }
});
```

### Answer - third pass

In line with the above, you shouldnt mix jquery and old-fashioned event handlers in html - again stick to jQuery if thats what you're writing

```
<h3><span style="cursor:pointer"><b>Text1</b></span></h3>
<div id="Text1" hidden="hidden">blahblah</div>
<hr id="line1" style="height:2px;border:none;color:#03930f;background-color:#03930f;" />
```

and

```
$('h3').on('click',function(){
    $('#Text1').toggle(1000,function(){
        if($(this).is(':visible')) {
             $('#line1').css('height','15px');
        }
        else { 
             $('#line1').css('height','2px');
        }
    });
});
```

Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xLxsctfk/3/

Comment: Thankyou very much. Really helpful. Yes I'm very new to this so I imagine lots of poor things are happening in my code. This is much cleaner.